# cant print rows in javascript when array is used

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

I am making a web page using HTML and js following is the code for that,
essentially I want to store the numbers generated by function and show it in column 6, so I am storing it in the array a and show it in column 6. But when I write to add the number for loop stops right there and control exits from the loop. ie. only one row and one column is displayed like

```
uid   day    time    source  destination     bus
 2
```

**rand.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var abc = 0;
a = new Array();
var b = 0;
//Returns a random number
function CreateLottoValues() 
{
return Math.floor(Math.random() * 20 + 1);
}
//create table
function UpdateTable() 
{

document.write("<table border=1 id='myTable' > ")
document.write("  <tr><td  >&nbsp; uid</td><td  >&nbsp; day</td><td 
>&nbsp;time</td><td >&nbsp;source</td><td >&nbsp;destination</td> <td 
>&nbsp;bus</td></tr>  ")
for (row=2; row<=30; row++) {
document.write("<tr>")
for (col=1; col<=6; col++) {
if(col==1){
document.write("<td >" +row+ "</td>")
}
else if(col==6){
for (var i = 0; i <= a.length; i++) {
document.write("<td>" + a[i] +"</td>")
}
}
else{
abc = CreateLottoValues();
a.add(abc); 
//tmp =row + col;
//document.getElementById(tmp).innerHTML = CreateLottoValues();
document.write("<td >" + abc + "</td>")
}                   
}
document.write("</tr>") 
}       
document.write("</table>")
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<center>

<div id="container">
<div id="header">
<h1>Welcome</h1> 
<p  id="demo"></p>

</div>

</div>
<input id="btn" type="button" value="Re-generate Numbers" 
onClick="UpdateTable()" />

</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone help me? thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Java is not the same thing as JavaScript.

Comment: Please check JavaScript's array docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On closer inspection, I found that your program won't run correctly because of this line:

```
a.add(abc);
```

This is because the variable `a` is an array, and to add elements to an array you use the `push` function
Replace `a.add(abc)` with `a.push(abc)`. I've also made a few other changes which you can understand by comparing this with your code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var abc = 0;
a = new Array();
var b = 0;
//Returns a random number
function CreateLottoValues() 
{
return Math.floor(Math.random() * 20 + 1);
}
//create table
function UpdateTable() 
{

document.write("<table border=1 id='myTable' > ")
document.write("  <tr><td  >&nbsp; uid</td><td  >&nbsp; day</td><td>&nbsp;time</td><td >&nbsp;source</td><td >&nbsp;destination</td> <td>&nbsp;bus</td></tr>  ")
for (row=2; row<=30; row++) {
document.write("<tr>")
for (col=1; col<=6; col++) {
if(col==1){
document.write("<td >" +row+ "</td>")
}
else if(col==6){
document.write("<td>");
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
document.write(a[i])
}
document.write("</td>");
a = new Array();
}
else{
abc = CreateLottoValues();
a.push(abc); 
//tmp =row + col;
//document.getElementById(tmp).innerHTML = CreateLottoValues();
document.write("<td >" + abc + "</td>")
}                   
}
document.write("</tr>") 
}       
document.write("</table>")
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<center>

<div id="container">
<div id="header">
<h1>Welcome</h1> 
<p  id="demo"></p>

</div>

</div>
<input id="btn" type="button" value="Re-generate Numbers" 
onClick="UpdateTable()" />

</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks a lot.... it works just fine ... so there is no function called array.add()?

Comment: Nope. Have a look at [this reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) for JavaScript arrays..